# Wordpress wp_mail: receiving duplicate emails when new post is published

Tags: php, wordpress, function

So I'm trying to send an email, when the new post is made:

```
add_action( 'added_post_meta', 'wpse168351_after_post_meta', 10, 4 );
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'wpse168351_after_post_meta', 10, 4 );
function wpse168351_after_post_meta( $meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value )
{
    
    $subject = 'hey';
    $message = 'my body message' ;
    $author_email = 'support@example.com';
    if ( 
        'question' == $meta_value) {
        wp_mail($author_email, $subject, $message);
    }
}
```

The problem with the above code, is that I receive multiple emails (duplicates).

So basically at the same second I get 4-5 emails for this one action.

My guess is that Wordpress is adding 4-5 entries to the database and this is why I'm getting more than 1 email.

I want to receive just one email.

This happens only when the new database record is created.

When I update already existing meta_value, it works fine (sends 1 email only)

Any way to solve this?

Help needed.

**UPDATE!**

got it working with `save_post` hook.

Comment: Find a more appropriate hook …? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/134667

Comment: I agree with CBroe, however just to offer an ugly alternative, you could keep track of `$post_id` in a global variable (probably an array, just in case multiple posts are created in the same request) and only invoke your email code if the current `$post_id` hasn't been used yet.

Comment: thanks CBroe, got it working with  `save_post` hook.